# Creating a map without using a struct as linked list

Tags: c

I have to create a struct for a map in C that contains a char* key and void* value which are stored together internally. Rather than having a linked list as an external struct, I have to allocate memory for a linked list cell which contains the link pointer, the key string, and the value together (contiguous).

The key and value data have to be stored directly in the cell and the cell has to be constructed at runtime. I get the beginning of this which would involve a struct like:

```
struct example {

    int count_of_list_elem;
    void *list;

}
```

But I don't know how this is **possible w/o using another struct** to form the linked list?

Would I have to create some cell within the struct itself, allocate memory to it and pass it three values? I'm just not sure how it would work.

EDIT: I need to use a void* array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard way of handling dynamically sized structures in C:

```
struct example {
    struct example *next;    /* linked list */
    int count_of_list_elem;
    char data[1];
}

struct example *bigone = malloc (sizeof (struct example) + 10000);
if (!bigone)
     // error
bigone -> next = NULL;
bigone -> count_of_list_elem = 10000;
memcpy (bigone -> data, <data source>);
```

Comment: If you could demonstrate using the void*, that would help.

Comment: @marchon:  I don't understand why that would be necessary.  A void pointer cannot be used directly:  it has to be cast to a actual type.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a `struct` before you define it, so that you can refer to it within the struct itself:

```
typedef struct tagMyStruct* my_struct_pointer;
typedef struct tagMyStruct
{
    char* KeyPtr;
    void* ValuePtr;
    my_struct_pointer NextPtr;
}   my_struct;

static my_struct_pointer _listHeadPtr = NULL;

my_struct_pointer AddNewCellToList(char* keyPtr, void* valuePtr)
{
    my_struct_pointer newCellPtr = malloc(sizeof(my_struct));
    newCellPtr->KeyPtr = keyPtr;
    newCellPtr->ValuePtr = valuePtr;
    newCellPtr->NextPtr = _listHeadPtr;
    _listHeadPtr = newCellPtr;
    return(newCellPtr);
}
```

You will need to malloc appropriate storage for the `Key` and `Value` before calling `AddNewCellToList`.

Comment: The first struct is some map and it should be storing a linked list of cells. I can't refer to any structs within the main struct.

Comment: @marchon Please could you explain why?  You can use pointer to a declared but undefined struct, as shown in my code above, without resorting to a `void*`.  For example: `typedef struct tagMyCell* cell_pointer;` in a cell.h header file and the implementation of `struct tagMyCell{}` held privately in a cell.c file and the cell_pointer type used in your map struct with no knowledge of the actual content of the memory it points to.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a struct type within its own definition:

```
struct example {
    int count_of_list_elem;
    void *list;
    struct example *next;
}
```

Your handle on the whole linked list is just a pointer to the first element:

```
struct example *head;
```

You will want to be careful when you create a new node to initialize its `next` pointer to `NULL` to indicate that there are (initially) no elements after it.